# Far open here from context menu

Tags: far-manager

Trying to install FarHere.inf tool that allows open far in selected location from context menu.

Far executable is in correct location:

```
FarHereLocation="C:\Program Files\Far Manager\Far.exe"
```

I have installed  `FarHere.inf`. Unfortunatly I still don't have far related menu in explorer right click menu. Why? What I do wrong?

Comment: Check in *Far Manager > Integration > Shell menu* for an option named "Far Manager 3 Here" or similar.

Comment: @harrymc What do you mean by `Integration`? Is it menu somewhere in Far application?

Comment: The name may have changed, or even disappeared. Search somewhere in the menu for an option with a similar name.